# Доступ к элементам класса наследника из класса родителя

Tags: c++, наследование

Каким образом можно работать с классом `С` в классе `В`?

```
class A
{
    public:
    int a;
    A();
}

class C;
class B : public A
{
    public:
    int b;
    C *c;
    B():A()
    {
        cout<<"Hi I`m B"<<endl;
        c->a = 5; //Тут ошибка:"Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x0F69533A в prog.exe: 
                  //0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу 0x00000090."
    }
}

class C : public B
{
    public:
    C();
}
```

Если создавать экземпляр класса а не указатель на него, то лучше не становится:
пишет, что класс `C` не содержит члена `a`

Comment: Вы используете не инициализированный указатель **c**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь обратиться к члену класса С через неинициализированный указатель, который не указывает на какой-либо корректный объект класса С. То есть, гадите в память. Указатель надо инициализировать - либо адресом существующего объекта класса С, либо создать прямо в конструкторе новый оператором new. Тогда все будет ОК.

Comment: Да, помогло, спасибо. Инициализировал его в конструкторе класса `B` вот так:
`с = new C`

Comment: @Nikita.L Все же интересно, какой код вы компилировали **на самом деле**...

Comment: @Harry, верно, мой код выглядит не совсем так, каюсь. В вопросе написан код "из головы". Смысл даже такого кода прослеживался и в моей проблеме мне помогли. Вам, как и всем остальным отвечающим - спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Компилятор просто не видит *определения* класса `C` при обращении к нему. Поэтому вам нужно просто вынести конструктор, определяя его после определения класса `C`.

Что, понятно, не снимает необходимости инициализировать указатель :)

Так что как вы откомпилировали и запустили этот код - лично я не понимаю.

Кстати, у вас еще и точки с запятой после определений классов отсутствуют. Скорее всего, вы даете не совсем тот код, с которым работаете - а это уже некорректно по отношению к отвечающим.

Comment: У него ошибка уже времени выполнения. Если бы не компилилось, не было бы никакого prog.exe. Видимо его код не совсем так выглядит, как он его привел. И ошибка именно из-за неинициализированного указателя.

Comment: @Voidificator Приведенный код не компилируется в принципе. И решать надо, начиная с этого. Почему я должен верить тому, что он пишет о сбое времени выполнения, а не тому, что **он же** пишет в вопросе - что его код не будет компилироваться? Задаешь неверный вопрос - будь готов к неверному ответу.